# Trusted clients

Tags: python, flask-oauthlib, authlib

I need to add trusted clients in SSO using Authlib. These clients are parts of my system and I don't need to the user confirmed it. Now, I use the next code for authorization:

```
@bp.route("/oauth/authorize", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def authorize():
    user = current_user()
    if not user:
        return redirect('/sign_in')
    if request.method == 'GET':
        grant = server.validate_consent_request(end_user=user)
        return render_template(
            "authorize.html",
            grant=grant,
            user=user
        )
    confirmed = request.form['confirm']
    if confirmed:
        # granted by resource owner
        return server.create_authorization_response(user)
    # denied by resource owner
    return server.create_authorization_response(None)
```

But how can I pre-register all my clients to they were confirmed automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be solved with:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    grant = server.validate_consent_request(end_user=user)
    if is_trust_client(grant.client):
        return server.create_authorization_response(user)
```

You can get the client model instance with `grant.client`. e.g. You define a column called `trusted`, then you can use `if grant.client.trusted` to tell if the client is trusted, if so, return the authorization response.